# Unable to connect locally to MySQL deployed in a GCP VM instance. (Using Plesk)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, portforwarding, vpc

I have an instance configured with Plesk+Ubuntu on GCP.
The server is in good condition.

This time, I want to connect to the DB created on Plesk from my iMac at home.
Currently, port 3306 is closed.
Next, I allowed 3306 connections in the VPC firewall settings.
However, port 3306 is not accepting any external access.
Local access is successful.

I have the following settings.
When creating the DB in plesk, I turned on the setting to accept access from the outside.
I have released 3306 for both upload/download in VPC.

Is there any other settings I need to do?

Comment: did you install ubuntu+plesk from the marketplace?

Comment: can you run `sudo apt install net-tools` and then `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 3306` and show us the output? Alternatively you can run `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:3306 -sTCP:LISTEN` or `sudo ss -tunlp | grep 3306`

Comment: As  jabbson said you need first check if the port is opened, in the instance, then you can follow Nimal V instructions. Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/mysql-remote-access

Answer (score 1):

1. open vm terminal: etc/mysql ..... ->bind-address = 0.0.0.0
2. restart mysql
3. create remote user
   then connect using mysql client from local computer

for more details refer the link bellow,

[Remote access to mysql on google compute engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oF4ku_7vxM)